# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TextEncoder

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using VSCode/Typescript React 3.4.3 for a React Native project and I'm having troubles at runtime with TextEncoder

The ts code:

```
...
var encoder = new TextEncoder();
var b: Uint8Array = encoder.encode(newName);
...
```

My tsconfig libs:

```
  "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es5", "es2017", "dom"]
```

This compile fines but it fails at runtime when it tries to create the instance of TextEncoder:

> "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TextEncoder"

I do not understand what is wrong here.

Any help appreciated

**EDIT 1**: Well the fact is that when you debug your JS code, it runs in Chrome which leads to success. But when you're not, you finish to discover that the JavaScriptCore neither support TextEncorder nor btoa.

So I have chosen to favor the use of npm modules ([text-encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-encoding) and [base-64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64)):

```
import * as encoding from 'text-encoding';
import {encode as btoa} from 'base-64'
...
var encoder = new encoding.TextEncoder();
...
```

Comment: Maybe your runtime doesn't have a `TextEncoder`. Which browser reports the problem?

Comment: The react native JSC.

Comment: How did you fix this ?

Comment: @j10 See Edit 1 in the question above about using nom modules.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are still having trouble in 2022 with this, or with a typescript project, perform the following steps:

1. Run: `yarn add text-encoding`
2. Run: `yarn add big-integer`
3. Add the following code to App.js or App.tsx:

---

```
const TextEncodingPolyfill = require('text-encoding');
const BigInt = require('big-integer')

Object.assign(global, {
    TextEncoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextEncoder,
    TextDecoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextDecoder,
    BigInt: BigInt,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error using stomp.js socket.

All I did was put

import * as encoding from 'text-encoding';

in App.js and works fine in both release and debug

Answer (score 0):

Textencoder need to be install some packages
https://github.com/anonyco/FastestSmallestTextEncoderDecoder